# Java automaticallly convert date from GMT to systemDefault Zone

Tags: java, date, web-services, timezone

I have an endPoint that get an object containing a java.util.date.
This data stored in DB have date in the format dd/MM/yyyy
Throughout the whole process java get the correct date, repository, service and the controller
But when I test the WS in Postman the date is incorrect.

Ex : in DB i have the date 31/03/2021, when i request the WS the result show me this
[image]

I think Java is considering the recovered date as GMT date, and when it's returned in the EndPoint it's converted to systemDefault Zone. (31/03/2021 00:00:00 -> 30/03/2021 22:00:00)

I just want java to return the date the same as it was recovered from DB without converting it to any TimeZone

I have i tried this solution once and it worked
[image]
Then i tried to externalize code to a new class utils, this led it to not working, i reverted the code to the working version, but it didn't work this time ...

I debuged the whole code and to the point just before return the date is not converted ...

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, it was Postman that was converting the date.

I have edited the endpoint to return the date as string and in the result of the test in Postman the date was exactly what i was expecting.

It's Postman that is considering the date as if it was GMT and not java. And as i'm not int GMT zone Postman convert the date to the SystemDefault TimeZone. This bring me to another question. Would the server or other adpater using my endPoint do the same thing as Postman ?